# SQL Server connection string troubles

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project, which uses this connection string:

````
<add name="Name" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.;initial catalog=MyDBName;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;" />```
````

Note: the data source value is `.`, this works but after I reset my pc and reinstalled SQL Server, it no longer works, I get an error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

until I change the `.` in the connection string to `DESKTOP-1V12LN7\SQLEXPRESS`.

My question is what does the value `.` in the connection string mean and why doesn't it work after reinstalling SQL Server?

Comment: `.` meant localhost with the default instance name. Your latest instance is named, so `.` on its own won't work (`.\SQLEXPRESS` or `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` would though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data source=.` (or `server=.` or `data source=(local)`, which are all equivalent) means : connect to the **local machine** and the **default, unnamed** instance of SQL Server - this is the default for all non-Express editions of SQL Server installed on your machine.

When you install SQL Server **Express**, by default, it doesn't get installed as the **default, unnamed** instance - but it uses a `SQLEXPRESS` instance name - so you need to change your connection string to:

- `.\SQLEXPRESS`
- `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`
- `DESKTOP-1V12LN7\SQLEXPRESS`